# detect if cursor is inside a link and get its href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

inside a contenteditable div need to detect if a cursor is inside a `<a></a>` range
if so in console I need `href` attribute
in the example below - if the cursor is on `google` console should be `https://google.com/`
any help, using jquery or plain js

```js
document.onselectionchange = () => {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var parent = selection.parentNode;
    console.log(parent);  // why undefined
   // if(parent is a link){console.log(parent.attr('href'));}
};
```

```css
.ed{width:50%; margin:0 auto; height:100vh; padding:9px; background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ed' id='ed' contenteditable>
<div>lorem</div>
<div><a href='https://google.com/'>google</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And BTW `parent` is JS reserved word.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#ed a').forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.href)
  });
})
```

```css
.ed {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 9px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ed' id='ed' contenteditable>
  <div>lorem</div>
  <div><a href='https://google.com/'>google</a></div>
  <div><a href='https://test.com/'>test.com</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to set focus or something else instead of mouseover. So only if cursor is inside, pls

Comment: @qadenza Just change it to click then?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the href attr only on **focusing the cursor** on the text **instead of mouse over** you can make use of *focusNode* and *instance type* on selection.

```css
.ed{width:50%; margin:0 auto; height:100vh; padding:9px; background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ed' id='ed' contenteditable>
<div>lorem</div>
<div><a href='https://google.com/'>google</a></div>
</div>
```

```js
document.onselectionchange = () => {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var parentElement = selection.focusNode.parentElement;
    if(parentElement instanceof HTMLAnchorElement){
       console.log(parent.href);
    }
};
```